# .htaccess - Recursively mapping slashes to underscores

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

G'day,

As the title says, I'm trying to make the url formatted as: `/this/is/mah/page/strucutre` to the file `this_is_mah_page_structure.php`.

Now, I have that working - except that I can't know the depth of the structure. Thus I need to have some recursion going on.

The working snipit I have for one and two replacements is:

```
    # map the slashes to underscores
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1_$2 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1_$2_$3 [L]
```

I have found this: [Htaccess recursively replace underscores with hyphens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132730/htaccess-recursively-replace-underscores-with-hyphens) which states how to do it (for different characters); and this https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-underscores-hyphens-seo-url/ which shows similar code. But I can't make it work.

Also, I found that .htaccess recursion can cause 500 errors - somewhere in the order of 10 loops - based on `LimitInternalRecursion`. From that, I tried replacing multiple with the one pass, but that had the unexpected outcome of doubling up the url.

This is the example from the other StackOverflow answer to give you an idea of what I've been testing. Any ideas / thoughts / direction?

(Rewrites underscores with hyphens - so it's the wrong side, but it's a start)

```
    RewriteEngine On

    # if there is only one underscore then repalce it by - and redirect
    RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=302]

    # if there are more than one underscores then "repeatedly" repalce it by - and set env var USCORE
    RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_([^_]*)_(.*) $1-$2-$3 [E=USCORE:1]

    # if USCORE env var is set then redirect
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_USCORE} =1
    RewriteRule ^([^_]+)$ /$1 [L,R=302]
```

**-- Edit and full solution --**

So it finally dawned on me through this post, that the presence / absence of R=302 (or 301) is what shifts the idea from "Map URL to file" (ie: transparent); to "Redirect". It should have been obvious, but I thought there was more too it.

The final solution is as @anubhava suggested, but I removed the `,R=301` and added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to prevent collision between the rules and real files/directories of the same name. (i.e. scripts.js, /images/yomomma.jpg, etc)

```
    # when there are more than one / then "recursively" replace it by _
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+/.+)$ $1_$2 [N,DPI]

    # when there is only one / then replace it by _ and redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1_$2 [NE,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had posted that answer about 5 years ago though now I think it can be further improved.

You may use these rules in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# if request is for a file [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# if request is for a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# then ignore all rules below
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# when there is only one / then replace it by _ and redirect
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1_$2 [NE,L,R=301]

# when there are more than one / then recursively replace / by _
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ $1_$2 [N,DPI]
```

Change `R=301` rule to `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1_$2 [L]` if you don't want an external redirect.

Comment: Oh! I think I understand something now I didn't before. The only difference between rewriting the URL and mapping the existing URL to a file of a different name is the R=301 (or 302). Is that right?

(Your answer rewrites the URL, but I took out the R=301 and it appears to do what I want now.)

Comment: Oh, well that's interesting - it seems that other files are now 404... Oh, oh wait. Putting 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f & RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d before it makes it work :)

Comment: Thanks @anubhava - appreciate your input. You've not only assisted me through to the final solution, but you have inadvertently taught me something. :)

Comment: I see your updates - I note that you don't re-declare the not-a-file & not-a-directory statements between rewrite statements. How does one tell when that's needed, and when you don't need to re-declare them?

Comment: See updated answer to ignore all rules for files and directories.

Comment: Are you aware of any reason why the above code would "suddenly" stop working? It's been working for ... Oh, a year to the day (almost) - but now it doesn't. To clarify, the "only one / to _" works, but the "recursive" one does not. Are you able to help?

Comment: Rule cannot become problematic. What may have happened is some upgrade at system level of OS, Apache or some config update at server level.

Comment: The server in question is a development server (CentOS 8). I also have this code on a cPanel server, and that is still working. Rather odd. Thanks.

Comment: If you'd be so kind, would you check this out? https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=9bd3c5a0-4002-4324-a82e-0065b7286f82 -> It doesn't work there either. (just noticed they had shareable links)

Comment: Oh just noted, never ever test these advanced rules on that website. It is buggy and rarely works. Best place to test is on your local Apache setup.

Comment: I see. It is also not working there either. I thought the lack of apparent recursion in that tester would explain why it isn't working. My testing implies that this is the case too, as /wobbly/donkey works, but /wobbly/donkey/tail 404's

Comment: So it was working for a year and not working all of a sudden right?

Comment: That's correct. Within a week of the same date. (May 5th 2020 is when we got it working)  The development server (which is just apache 2.4 on CentOS 8 - no cPanel) shows 404 once you get past more than one / in the middle of the URL (ie two levels deep). While a live cPanel machine has it all working fine.

Comment: I have updated with bit more optimisation. On my local Apache `2.4.46` it is working well and redirecting `localhost/this/is/mah/page/strucutre` to `localhost/this_is_mah_page_strucutre`

Comment: The 301 throws me, keep forgetting to remove it. I'm trying to map https://localhost/this/is/mah/page/structure to localhost:/user/html/this_is_mah_page_structure.php (the php bit is done elsewhere currently). I removed the R=302, and it doesn't work on anything past /mah/page level. (same outcome as the original code)

Comment: At this point may I request you to post a new question with more details please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67396892/htaccess-recursively-mapping-slashes-to-underscores-internal-redirect as requested.