# .htaccess - Recursively mapping slashes to underscores (internal redirect)

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Related to a previous Question: [.htaccess - Recursively mapping slashes to underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61607956/htaccess-recursively-mapping-slashes-to-underscores/61623744?noredirect=1#comment119126027_61623744)

The code that was listed as the "full solution" worked for 12 months. Then stopped working. The `.htaccess` code wasn't changed either - just to make things harder.

**The Question**

Can anyone help me achieve *The Desired Outcome*?

**The Desired Outcome**

Take https ://domain.com/this/is/mah/page/structure and show the file /this_is_mah_page_strucutre.php which lives in the root of the website.

**The Code Currently**

The below is contents from the [htaccess](/questions/tagged/htaccess) file

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
Options All -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    DirectorySlash off

    # Error Redirects
        ErrorDocument 404 /incs/404.php

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
        RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

    # remove .php
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

        # map the .php extension
        RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

    # map the slashes to underscores
        # when there are more than one / then "recursively" replace it by _
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# This next line appears to be the problem
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+/.+)$ $1_$2 [N,DPI]


# This next section appears to be doubling up, but was originally meant to catch anything that missed the previous block
        # when there is only one / then replace it by _ and redirect
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1_$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

**The Possible Problem**

As noted, `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+/.+)$ $1_$2 [N,DPI]` doesn't seem to work as intended.

If https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/?share=9bd3c5a0-4002-4324-a82e-0065b7286f82 is to be believed, then what is happening is that the [N] isn't causing the recursion (a) I require, and (b) it used to provide.

The MadeWithLove tester outcome states that `/this/is/mah/page/structure` is becoming `/this_is/mah/page/structure`.

I have tried rejiggering the PCRE RegEx, and so has @anubhava - but have been unable to get it working.

**The Server**

The server is using version `2.4.37-30.module_el8.3.0+561+97fdbbcc` for httpd and is running on CentOS 8. The code in question was migrated from CentOS 7 about 5 months go, and it's been working happily till about the last 7 days.

As far as the Apache settings and .htaccess file, nothing has changed within the last two weeks.

Comment: Would you be able to enable trace level `RewriteLog` using this directive in Apache conf: `LogLevel info rewrite:trace4`

Comment: I would, but it appears I don't need to - both answers below achieve my goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```sh
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options All -Indexes -MukltiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    DirectorySlash off
    # Error Redirects
    ErrorDocument 404 /incs/404.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # remove .php
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

    # map the slashes to underscores
    # when there are more than one / then "recursively" replace it by _
    # This next line appears to be the problem
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ $1_$2 [N,DPI]

    # map the .php extension
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I like the idea of filtering out the real files / folders prior to continuing on. I hadn't thought of that - until now, I'd been filtering them out per block. Yours is far more elegant.

Comment: Oh. Do you think that the "doubling up" bit is required at all now that it's searching for / with anything after it? I've commented it out, and it seems fine. And of course, logically it makes sense that it's not required.

Comment: If filtering out the real files / folders rule is there then there is no need for further checks before each rule.

Comment: I was talking about the `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1_$2 [L]` - that's what commented out. And yes, that `-d` & `-f` early was a good idea.

Comment: Yes that rule can be commented out

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ %1_%2 [L]
```

So, your full htaccess be:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
Options All -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    DirectorySlash off

    # Error Redirects
        ErrorDocument 404 /incs/404.php

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
        RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

    # remove .php
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
        RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]

        # map the .php extension
        RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)\/(.*)$
        RewriteRule ^ %1_%2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This also worked. I'm not sure what the right play is here for me if there are two answers. I've Awarded the green tick to @anubhava due to his help from the previous question (post answer, a year later).

Comment: @Mark, you can upvote me. And accept anubhava's. Its up to you.